# Add breadcrumb in Checkout page (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, breadcrumbs

How to add "Breadcrumbs" on the Checkout page (magento 1.9)?

Though by default the "Checkout" page does not contain breadcrumbs,

but I want to add those on my "Checkout" page.

I called them in my template with

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml(); ?>
```

All added the "Breadcrumb block" in my checkout layout

but still it is not getting displayed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109771/set-breadcrumb-for-magento-one-step-checkout-page

Comment: there is no default breadcrumb if you want you can put static breadcrumb , IF you want static breadcrumb then tell me I will  give you the answer

Comment: Yes sure Murtuza. You can suggest me all possible solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default checkout page does not have breadcrumb if you want static breadcrumb then you can add by following `xml` code.

you can add this xml in your theme `local.xml` file

this handler is based on default magento setup please check handler if you have custom checkout extension please change handler as per your own.

if you want to add intermediate breadcrumb then add `addCrumb` code.

```
<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
   <reference name="breadcrumbs"> 
      <action method="addCrumb"> <!--add breadcrumb-->
         <name>home</name>
           <params> 
             <label>Home</label> 
             <title>Home</title> 
             <link></link> 
           </params> 
      </action>
      <action method="addCrumb"> <!--add breadcrumb-->
         <name>checkout</name>
           <params> 
             <label>checkout</label> 
             <title>checkout</title> 
             <link>{{baseSecureUrl}}checkout/onepage/</link> 
           </params> 
      </action> 
   </reference> 
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Comment: You are always welcome :)

Comment: Sure. I am learning Mangeto 1.9. So there are many basic questions I have put on my account. You can check it and answer them also, so that for all questions I can get a definite answer. Thanks and regards

Comment: Sure I will check and if possible then I will I answer